# Add value, text and state to array for all checkboxes within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, underscore.js

I would like to get and add the value, text and state of a checkbox to an array in order to convert to json.

The generated html looks like this.

```
<div id="utilityMultiSelect" class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="widgetMultiSelect form-control multiselect-checkbox" style="height: auto; border: solid 1px #c0c0c0; display: inline-table; width: 100%;">
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-127">Heat and steam</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-26">Diesel</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-19">Gas</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-16">Water</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-10">Energy</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-1">Electricity</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="1">Natural Gas</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="8">_Costs</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got the following so far..

```
$("#searchForm").on('submit', function () {
        //get checkboxes for div and map to array with value, text and state
        var selectedUtilities = $('#utilityMultiSelect input:checkbox')
            .map(function () {
                return
                //$(this).val()
                //$(this).is(':checked');
            }).get();
```

I can return the value or state, how do I transform it similar to a selectlistitem with a value, text and selected? Is there a nice way of doing so with jQuery or using underscorejs?

Comment: Side note: The `!important;` part of your `style` attribute does nothing whatsoever. If you meant to apply it to the `display` style, it needs to be `display: block !important;` (no `;` after `block`). But it's rare to need `!important` on inline styles, as they "win" over any stylesheet style (unless the stylesheet style has `!important`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object to return from `map`:

```
return {
    value:   this.value,
    text:    $(this).closest("label").text(),
    checked: this.checked
};
```

Live Example:

```js
$("#btn-show").on('click', function() {
  var selectedUtilities = $('#utilityMultiSelect input:checkbox')
    .map(function() {
      return {
          value:   this.value,
          text:    $(this).closest("label").text(),
          checked: this.checked
      };
    }).get();
  console.log(selectedUtilities);
});
```

```html
<div id="utilityMultiSelect" class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="widgetMultiSelect form-control multiselect-checkbox" style="height: auto; border: solid 1px #c0c0c0; display: inline-table; width: 100%;">
    <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-127">Heat and steam</label>
    <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-26">Diesel</label>
    <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-19">Gas</label>
    <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-16">Water</label>
    <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-10">Energy</label>
    <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-1">Electricity</label>
    <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="1">Natural Gas</label>
    <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="8">_Costs</label>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn-show" value="Click To Show Selected">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note that I used `this.value` rather than `$(this).val()` and `this.checked` rather than `$(this).is(":checked")`. While those jQuery-isms work, they're completely unnecessary here. The `HTMLInputElement` has `value` and `checked` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here you with a solution without `map` rather with `each`

```js
var selectedUtilities = [];
$("#btn-show").on('click', function () {
  $('#utilityMultiSelect input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    selectedUtilities.push({
      value: $(this).val(),
      text: $(this).closest("label").text(),
      checked: $(this).prop('checked')
    });
  });
  console.log(selectedUtilities);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="utilityMultiSelect" class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="widgetMultiSelect form-control multiselect-checkbox" style="height: auto; border: solid 1px #c0c0c0; display: inline-table; width: 100%;">
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-127">Heat and steam</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-26">Diesel</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-19">Gas</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-16">Water</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-10">Energy</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="-1">Electricity</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="1">Natural Gas</label>
        <label style="display: block; !important;" class="multiselect-checkbox-on"><input checked="checked" class="multiSelectCheckBox" name="" type="checkbox" value="8">_Costs</label>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn-show" value="Click To Show Selected">
```

Hope this will help you.